# Can't get clean output in my MATLAB implementation of Canny-Deriche

Tags: algorithm, matlab, feature-detection, edge-detection

My code so far is:

```
function imgg = derichefilter1(x, k, a, b, c)
osize = size(x);
x = double(x);
a = double(a);
b = double(b);
c = double(c);
k = double(k);
y1 = zeros(osize(1),osize(2));
y2 = zeros(osize(1),osize(2));
y1(:,1) = a(1)*x(:,1);
y1(:,2) = a(1)*x(:,2) + a(2)*x(:,1) + b(1)*y1(:,1);
for ii=3:osize(2)
    y1(:,ii) = a(1)*x(:,ii) + a(2)*x(:,ii-1) + b(1)*y1(:,ii-1) + b(2)*y1(:,ii-2);
end

y2(:,osize(2)-1) = a(3)*x(osize(2));
for ii=(osize(2)-2):-1:1
    y2(:,ii) = a(3)*x(:,ii+1) + a(4)*x(:,ii+2) + b(1)*y2(:,ii+1) + b(2)*y2(:,ii+2);
end
imgg = c*(y1+y2);

function imgg = derichefilter2(x, k, a, b, c)
imgg = derichefilter1(x,k,a(1:4),b,c(1));
imgg = (derichefilter1(imgg',k,a(5:8),b,c(2)))';

function [mask magn] = nonmaxsupp(x, y)
magn = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
argu = atan2(y,x);
argu = argu/pi*4;
argu = int32(round(argu));
argu(argu == 4) = 0;
argu(argu < 0) = argu(argu < 0) + 4;
mask = boolean(zeros(size(x)));
for ii = 2:(size(x,1)-1)
    for jj = 2:(size(x,2)-1)
        switch argu(ii,jj)
            case 0
                mask(ii,jj) = (max(magn(ii,jj+1),magn(ii,jj-1)) <= magn(ii,jj));
            case 1
                mask(ii,jj) = (max(magn(ii-1,jj+1),magn(ii+1,jj-1)) <= magn(ii,jj));
            case 2
                mask(ii,jj) = (max(magn(ii-1,jj),magn(ii+1,jj)) <= magn(ii,jj));
            case 3
                mask(ii,jj) = (max(magn(ii+1,jj+1),magn(ii-1,jj-1)) <= magn(ii,jj));
        end
    end
end

function imgg = hystthres(x,Tl,Th)
imgg = (x>Th);
limg = (x>=Tl);
osize = size(x);
nTh = 0;
for ii = 1:osize(1)
    for jj = 1:osize(2)
        if imgg(ii,jj)
            nTh = nTh + 1;
        end
    end
end
c = zeros(1,nTh); r = zeros(1,nTh); nTh=0;
for ii = 1:osize(1)
    for jj = 1:osize(2)
        if imgg(ii,jj)
            nTh = nTh + 1;
            c(nTh) = ii; r(nTh) = jj;
        end
    end
end
imgg = bwselect(limg,r,c,8);

function imgg = derichecomplete(x, alph, Tl, Th)
k = (1 - exp(-alph))^2/(1 + 2*alph*exp(-alph) - exp(-2*alph));
as = zeros(1,8);
as(1) = k;
as(2) = k*exp(-alph)*(alph-1);
as(3) = k*exp(-alph)*(alph+1);
as(4) = -k*exp(-2*alph);
as(5:8)=as(1:4);
b = zeros(1,2);
b(1) = 2*exp(-alph);
b(2) = -exp(-2*alph);
cs = [1,1];
ax = [0,1,-1,0,as(5:8)];
cx = [-(1 - exp(-alph))^2,1];
ay = [ax(5:8),ax(1:4)];
cy = [cx(2) cx(1)];

deriches = derichefilter2(x, k, as, b, cs);
derichex = derichefilter2(deriches, k, ax, b, cx);
derichey = derichefilter2(deriches, k, ay, b, cy);
[mask mag] = nonmaxsupp(derichex, derichey);
mag(~mask) = 0;
imgg = hystthres(mag,Tl,Th);

clc; clear all; close all;
imagepath = input('Enter the image path in single quotes: ');
alph = input('Enter the value of alpha to be used: ');
Tl = input('Enter the value of Tl to be used: ');
Th = input('Enter the value of Th to be used: ');
imgg = imread(imagepath);
szzz = size(size(imgg));
if szzz(2) == 3
    osize = size(imgg);
    hystf = boolean(zeros(osize(1:2)));
    for ii=1:3
        hystf = hystf | derichecomplete(imgg(:,:,ii),alph,Tl,Th);
    end
else    
    hystf = derichecomplete(imgg,alph,Tl,Th);
end
imshow(hystf);
```

My output on the image on the [Canny-Deriche Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deriche_edge_detector) [image] [image]

I can't seem to find an error because I followed the instructions there and on the [Canny edge detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) page to the letter. I've just implemented the algorithm as it is, and still can't seem to produce the same output. The features are thick and edgy, instead of smooth as on the Wikipedia pages.

EDIT: [Dropbox link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35186704/Deriche.zip) to code/image so you don't have to copy/paste it.

Comment: How did you define `boolean`? It's not a built-in function, so I substituted `logical` and got a different result altogether. Are you using the same parameters (1.5, 20, 40)?

Comment: As @Emre mentioned `logical` is the proper matlab command to cast variables as booleans. However, note that for initializing variables you can also just use `false(size)` rather than `logical(zeros(size))`

Comment: @Emre, I did use exactly the same parameters. I'll try logical, and also Dennis' solution.

Comment: It didn't work. I got exactly the same result with `false`. Will try `logical(zeros(size))`
I didn't define `boolean`, I thought it was built-in.

Comment: Exactly the same result. I'm using R2011b, if it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best not to assume the Wikipedia has it right? I would ask the uploading author by email for his code. You can also find some MATLAB implementations [here](http://en.pudn.com/downloads169/sourcecode/windows/multimedia/detail781617_en.html).

Comment: Thanks for all your help, @Emre. The Wikipedia user in question has deleted his account, and from the looks of it, this article was one of the only contributions he made. I'll look through the MATLAB implementation there, and try to edit my work to match the logic.

Comment: He hasn't deleted his account; he just hasn't written on his user page. You can leave a message on [his talk page](http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskuse_s_wikipedistou:Zbysek.nemec) [+[cz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Zbysek.nemec)].

Comment: @Emre Ah. Okay. What I find more disturbing, though, is that you get different results with `logical`, while I don't. Could you post them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not processing the correct file.  I applied your function to the full resolution image http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5e/Sunflowers_in_July.jpg and the result looked fine

If I apply your function to the 50K preview file, I get the result you show above.